# Forcing 644 Permissions on Files with ProFTPd

Tags: permissions, ftp, ubuntu-12.04, file-permissions, proftpd

We have an `Ubuntu 12.04` server set up with `ProFTPd` for users to upload files. Each user has their own account and are jailed to their directory.

Normally, everything works fine, they get `644` permissions on created/uploaded files, and `755` permissions on created/uploaded folders.

The problem is, occasionally some files will get uploaded with `600` permissions (or changed after uploading, I'm not sure?), so they are not readable to anyone but the owner. Is there any way to **lock/force** permissions to `644` on files?

I know I can take away permissions with `umask` but I don't want this, I want to *stop* the user reducing the permissions too much, so they shouldn't be able to go below 644 (rw- r-- r--)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't control ftp in the way you want, you could only limit chmod for some users entirely or allow it. There isn't a middle way. Maybe you could use auditd to monitor for changes and then take action on them, but that would be really complicated.

Edit: Limiting chmod in proftpd:

```
    <Limit SITE_CHMOD>
         DenyAll   
    </Limit>
```

Comment: Do you know if it's easy to disable chmod with ProFTPd?

Comment: Yes, you just use the limit directive:   
<Limit SITE_CHMOD>
    DenyAll
</Limit> (I don't know how to format this in the comments)

Comment: Thanks! :) I would have voted your answer up too, but I can't do that until I have 15 reputation :(